# Threads output player

Tags: java, multithreading, static

Can someone tell me what would be the output to this code and why? I tried doing it myself but it wouldn't work.

```
public static class Player extends Thread {
    int id;
    Player op;

    public Player(int n){
        id = n;
    }

    public void connect(Player other) {
        op = other;
    }

    public void run() {
        if(op != null) {
            try {
                op.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(" INTERRUPTED");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("PLAYER ID ="+id);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player p1=new Player(1);
        Player p2=new Player(2);
        p1.connect(p2);
        p1.start();
        p2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What wouldn't work? Why don't you run it yourself to see the output?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use the static modifier on a class unless it's nested inside another class, so what you have doesn't compile. Once you fix that by deleting the static keyword, the program runs and prints out:

```
PLAYER ID =2
PLAYER ID =1
```

The main thread initializes the p1 and p2 threads, starts them, and exits. The threads are non-daemon threads so the JVM stays running until they're done.

The p1 thread calls join on the p2 thread, causing p1 to go dormant until p2 is finished. p2 has its op field set to null, so it executes, prints output and finishes (notifying p1 as it terminates). At that point p1 wakes up from waiting on p2, prints output, and terminates.

So as long as only one thread calls connect on the other, the connecting thread waits for the other to finish before printing out its output. If you add a line `p2.connect(p1);` before starting the threads then you should get a deadlock as the two threads are waiting for each other forever.

p1 isn't guaranteed to start before p2. If p2 happens to get its run method executed first then p1 joins to a dead thread so it doesn't have to wait; the result is the same (p2 finishing first) regardless of which thread begins first.